# auto gradle downloading from svn repository

Tags: java, spring, gradle

I have problems with configure my build.gradle for download jar and pom from svn repository. For example, i have url:

`https://svn.code.sf.net/p/springframework/svn/repos/repo-ext/javax/xml/crypto/xmldsig/1.0/`

and i want did like this `compile group: 'com.sun.xml.wss', name: 'xws-security', version: '3.0'`

Also, manual download is wrong way.

**UPD** this is build.gradle file of backend project

```
apply plugin: 'java'
dependencies {
compile group: 'org.glassfish.metro', name: 'wssx-api', version: '2.1.1-b09'
compile group: 'com.sun.xml.wss', name: 'xws-security', version: '3.0'

compile project(':pp-backend')
}
```

Comment: Can you post your whole build.gradle file?

Comment: @Ethan yeap. I'm update the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not downloading from [maven central](http://search.maven.org/) (which is configured in Gradle by default), you should configure the repository to download from using the 'repositories' closure:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url 'https://svn.code.sf.net/p/springframework/svn/repos/repo-ext/'
    }
}
```

Then, in the 'dependencies' closure, just add:

```
compile group: 'javax.xml.crypto', name: 'xmldsig', version: '1.0'
```

See more info in [Dependency Management Basics](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html#N1062C)

Comment: can i download files from svn repo by gradle? If yes, i can every build check if exist file. If not exist, then download it and use in project from specific folder, resources, for example. Sorry for my english, it's bad :)

Comment: The code above will download the **'xmldsig'** dependency from **'https://svn.code.sf.net/p/springframework/svn/repos/repo-ext/'** svn repo, if it doesn't already exist. Am I missing something?